# How do I open .ai files on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, conversion, png, adobe-illustrator

Specifically this file
https://stock.adobe.com/stock-photo/flux-vague-de-dollars-illustration/35571058
I tried to rename the file with .pdf extension, but FoxIt would not open it.
I tried to install Inkscape but it would not open it either. 
I tried to convert from .ai to .png with FFMPEG, but it gave an error ".\AdobeStock_35571058_WM.ai: Invalid data found when processing input".

I need to convert it to PNG format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed Ghostscript using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org), but I had to install the 32 bit version with `--forcex86`, and I had to use `ghostscript.app` package as `ghostscript` package would not install anything with `--forcex86`. Then I used [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/) which was already installed with Chocolatey. [XnView only supports 32 bit Ghostview](http://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?t=1228). I open the `.ai` file with XnView and it was able to open. I could change the raster DPI with Tools > Options > Read/Write > Read > EPS > DPI and I set it to 300. Then when I open the file, I could resize and save as PNG.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lot of free software, but my recommendation would be to launch it with PaintShop Pro, like this: http://www.paintshoppro.com/en/pages/ai-file/ because it is very simple with editing, and since it is an Illustrator file, some software can mess with the quality and PaintShop Pro.

Comment: Can you back up your assertion that "some software can mess with the quality" ? As it stands, this reads as a promotion for PSP.

Answer (score 0):

`.ai` is the file extension for Adobe Illustrator vector graphic files.

You will need to use a program which can edit vector graphics to work with this file. The obvious choice is Illustrator, but I believe [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) can also open Illustrator documents.

Comment: So, Inkscape does have its benefits, but it has trouble incorporating a lot of Illustrator's features.  This includes anchoring as a result of scissors tools (as I have found out :)

Comment: @Daneolog Right -- in this case it sounds like the OP just wants to export the file as a bitmap, though. No need for any fancy editing.